# issue of including QtGui files in building a c++ based software

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I am not expert in c++ and I am trying to install a [software](http://people.bss.phy.cam.ac.uk/~rea1/ezys/code/) which is based on `c++`; during the building the files in `Qt Creator`, once it reaches to this line to include

```
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui/QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
```

it shows error

```
/home/ubuntu/Ezys/source/Ezys_GUI/ezys_gui.h:12: error: QtGui/QMainWindow: No such file or directory
 #include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
                             ^
```

I checked the place of `QtGui`, which is `/usr/include/qt4/QtGui` and all files are there. I do not know what is the reason cannot find the files and include them. 
Could someone please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong kit for your project in Qt Creator, probably one based on Qt 5. See if you have a kit for Qt 4 or [create a new one](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html), then [reconfigure your project to use it](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-configuring-projects.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem, I was compiling with QT5, however, I have installed qt4 core, Thanks again